# Angular 2 - how to consume data from local json?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Thanks for every one who jumping into this for helping me . ***NOW its working like charm***

Thanks all

Could someone tell me how to use local JSON data?

I am not sure what am missing in configuration (problem might be in HTTP config). Below is my file structure.

```
├───app
    about.component.html
about.component.ts
app.component.css
app.component.html
app.component.spec.ts
app.component.ts
app.module.ts
app.routing.ts
dataservice.ts
home.component.html
home.component.ts
dummy.json
└───environments
```

myService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class dataService implements OnInit {
  constructor(private Http: Http) {}
  private _url: string = "assets/js/dummy.json";
  ngOnInit() {}
  gethomedata() {
    return this.Http.get(this._url).map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

homeComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class home implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: Http, private dataService: dataService) {}
  home = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.gethomedata().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('home', data);
      this.home.push(data);
    })
  }
}
```

When I run, it shows 404 not found error. 
Can tell me where I did wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to place json inside  assets folder

Comment: place what? in asset folder

Comment: Cheg, when you compile your angular app, you have in a "dist" folder, your index.html, your .css, your .js and a folder called assets (copy of your folder "assets" in your scr/assets). Use this folder to put all you need read: images, .json to read, etc, etc

Comment: but i've not using any other basic folder structure

Comment: ├───app
├───assets
│   └───js
                 dummy.json
└───environments

now i have changed as you said. can u tell me how to access it?

Comment: The URL should be : `assets/dummy.json`

Comment: @YounesM pls check my updated question

Comment: Since you put your json in a folder it should be : `assets/js/dummy.json` Can we have a look at your angular-cli.json file?

Comment: @YounesM now its working fine as expected :)  thank ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, you have two options:

1. You serve the json as an asset and retrieve it via the `HttpClient`.
2. You put the json in the source code, you import it in your typescript and when it is compiled, it is transformed into an object by webpack.

In practice, the second point is not doable as far as I know, because it involves the modification of the webpack configuration and it is not currently possible with Angular.

Comment: Noel pls check my updated question i've attached screenshots

Comment: the error shows a different path (assets/dummy.json) than what you say is in your directory (assets/js/dummy.json)

Comment: sorry for delayed response . its working fine now :)